# Why do we not instantiate the filesystem class like other classes using the new keyword?

Tags: java, io, filesystems

I am doing some Java homework and we are currently studying IO and files in java.

In the directions it asks for us to instantiate a filesystem class. However this doesn't seem possible without using the following syntax. How can I better understand this?

FileSystem fs  = FileSystems.getDefault();

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `FileSystem` is an abstract class, so you can't create one with `new`.

Comment: [Creational Design Patterns](https://www.baeldung.com/creational-design-patterns). See also [`Calendar.getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()). Different classes do (and implement) different things.